# SFML library : strange error

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm learning SFML library and i picked a code from the tutorial. it opens a window and it should make me able to close it again but when i close it it says

```
Debug Error!
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - stack around variable 'App' was corrupted.

and then the console stops working.
this is my code:

int main()
{
    // Create the main window
    sf::Window App(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "SFML Events");

    while (App.IsOpened())
    {
        // Process events
        sf::Event Event;
        while (App.GetEvent(Event))
        {
            // Close window : exit
            if (Event.Type == sf::Event::Closed)
                App.Close();

            // Escape key : exit
            if ((Event.Type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) && (Event.Key.Code == sf::Key::Escape))
                App.Close();
        }

        // Display window on screen
        App.Display();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;// = return 0
}
```

linking to the debug libraries are

```
sfml-system.lib
sfml-window.lib
sfml-system-d.lib//these are debug files
sfml-window-d.lib
```

if i ramove the first 2 and built my program it doesn't give errors but when i open it it says :

> the application was unable to start correctly (0xc0150002). click ok to close the application

i have a 64 bit computer. and in microsoft vc++ 2010 i can do build solution or debug and i always do build solution.

and i am building in release mode but i have also tried both and they both didn't work

could someone please tell me what i could do to prevent this from happening or how this comes.

Comment: If you build a debug version, why not run it in the debugger? At least you will see _where_ the problem is.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg sir, i have tried but not working

Comment: Besides, should you really call `App.Display` _all the time_? In most other frameworks you tell the app object to display _once_, before entering the main event loop. Also, won't this try to display the window again after it been closed, thereby giving you your problem?

Comment: I think you need to build SFML specifically for VS2010, the delivered libs don't really work.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg   ,xeo got it ,i had to put my DLL's in the debug file next to my .exe file  is it worthy to make this answer or shoul i remove the question

Comment: Put the dll and exe in same folder works? at least there are potential problems because you app and the sfml depends on different versions of c-runtime libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these application startup issues,it is always a good idea to check if all dlls in the dependency closure are accessible - that is, are they all in the search PATH? We usually use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check which dlls are missing, or use [gflags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for runtime diagnostic

While put your dlls with your exe in same folder works, it does not scale well, one way I usually do is put the library path in PATH environment variable.

And one thing to notice, sfml comes with prebuilt binrary for vs2005 and vs2008, as you are using vs2010, the underlying c runtime library(msvcrt) is different, there would be potential problems - you would better build sfml from source yourself using vs2010 or use vs2005/vs2008, just to be consistent

Answer (score 0):

if you wouldnt like to use DLLs and would like to compile SFML into exe, here is tutorial:
2.0 http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-vc.php
you need to add preprcessor directive SFML_STATIC , and include additional libs u are using in your program into linker -> input

Answer (score 0):

I also had some related problems when I first time used this (and equivalent libs). Here is some points to take in count:

1. Do not use precompiled libraries/dlls. Learn how to use CMake, boost_build (boost libraries), Scons (mongoDB) etc. and build libraries according to currently used compiler/platform (of course if there is such possibility). After some time this process became pretty easy and simple and this will save a lot of time later for other projects.
2. Read SFML tutorials on making a simple project. They are easy to read and understand. May try to generate also examples with CMake and build them to see how they work. Another good tutorial is the book on SFML programming (which have a huge push on using C++11, which I think is great).
3. As pointed out add SFML_STATIC to "Preprocessor definitions" if don't want to use DLLs and I think is better to set "Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)" in linker options (if I correctly understood from "and then the console stops working" statement).
4. Better to place libsndfile-1.dll and openal32.dll in release/debug folder where app is generated, from what I saw VC++ have a bad behavior on finding dlls from provided paths.